# how does sed command work with multiple groups

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I'm trying parse some text files, and I need to use sed command to find and replace.

example:

```
'a b' replace with 'b a'
'c d' replace with 'd c'
'e f' replace with 'f e'
```

sample input

```
xa bx
xc dx
xe fx
```

sample output

```
xb ax
xd cx
xf ex
```

I've tried the following code

```
sed 's/\[ace][:space:]\[bdf]/\1 \2/g'
```

I get the following errors in the terminal:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS
```

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to delete x's and swap remaining two words?? I didn't understand the question

Comment: Don't you want to replace `c d`? I think you meant `d c` as the 2nd line of the expected output.

Comment: Note that even if it worked, your command would do too much.: it would also translate `a f` to `f a`, which may not be what you wanted.

Comment: I've edited to clarify the question. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that need fixing:

- `[:space:]` is a bare POSIX character class that does not work like it should when it is outside of a bracket expression, you must wrap this with `[...]` => `[[:space:]]`
- `\[ace]` matches an `[ace]` text, not a `a`, `c` or `e` letters because you escape the `[` and "ruined" the bracket expression (made it a literal string)
- In order to define capturing groups, you need to use `\(...\)` (in  a POSIX BRE pattern, in POSIX ERE, if you add `-E`/`-r` option, you need `(...)`) around the part of the pattern you need to refer to from the replacement pattern
- To actually remove what you do not need, your pattern must match that text. You may use `.*` to match any text, `[^[:space:]]*`  to match any 0+ non-whitespace chars
- To swap the text, you need to use `\2 \1`, not `\1 \2` in the replacement pattern.

So, you may consider

```
sed 's/.*\([ace]\)[[:space:]]\([bdf]\).*/\2 \1/g' file
```

Or, if the lines to be handled must follow `[0+_non_whitespaces][ace][space][def][0+_non_whitespaces]` pattern:

```
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*\([ace]\)[[:space:]]\([bdf]\)[^[:space:]]*$/\2 \1/g' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/IKpgBM).

Comment: This hits the nail on the head. I was looking to better learn and understand how to use complicated group. This helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass several patterns to sed, separated by `;`, so this command should do the trick :

```
sed 's/a b/b a/g;s/c d/d c/g;s/e f/f e/g'
```

Edit: from @RavinderSingh13's proposition, it's better to just do:

```
sed -e 'y/(a b)(c d)(e f)/(b a)(d c)(f e)/'
```

Comment: thank you. this answer works, but I was looking specficially to learn how to use grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(tested with samples provided).

```
sed 'y/ab/ba/;y/cd/dc/;y/ef/fe/'  Input_file
```

OR more simpler:

```
sed 'y/abcdef/badcfe/' Input_file
```

***From `man sed`:***

> y/source/dest/ Transliterate  the  characters in the pattern space
>   which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking specifically to learn how to use grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use grouping at all - you need to use brackets - and your character class (`[:space:]`) is wrong.

```
sed 's/\([ace]\)[[:space:]]\([bdf]\)/\2 \1/g' sample_input
```

I have no idea why you'd get "invalid reference \3" since there's no "\3" in your command.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was trying to understand. Wiktor provided some explanations to things I had misunderstood.